# How do I get an NPC out of my house/room?

Tags: terraria-console

I have a huge house in Terraria with rooms instead of a big town with multiple houses.

The first floor is crafting and storage (Cole the NPC), the next floor is my room. It has my bed, a dresser, a golden chest, a red banner and a platinum chandelier and half stone walls, half wood walls.

There are three more floors that are supposed to be rooms for my NPCs. One has a bar, barstools, a cooking pot, a keg, and a table and 2 chairs(the merchant), the next one has a shade wood table, a dresser, 2 chairs and a banquet table (the nurse) and the one at the top has a bench, a dresser and a table and 2 chairs (empty).

But Hanno my dye trader stays in my room !

I don't know why it bothers me so much but is there a way for me to get her out ? (I added all the details because, is it what's in my room that makes her stay in there? Is it because my room is the biggest?)
And the creepiest part, every time I respawn in my bed, she stands right there at the end of my bed.

Please tell me there's a way to get her out of my room.

Comment: How is the NPC a nuisance? It shouldn't be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try making your room invalid temporarily.

An example would be replacing the floor completely with platforms.

Once that is done the NPC should pick a different home to live in, go somewhere else in the world for a day and come back and they should be elsewhere (I think day/night changes cause NPCs to warp home).

I believe you should be safe to fix your room once that is done.

[This page](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/House) has all of the details about how houses work and you may be able to use that to modify your room to be invalid by that measure.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the y button menu go to housing and walk to the room you want Hanno to go to press a while your in the housing for Hanno on the housing menu. Press a while yoor cursor is on his face.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is remove the light source, door and a bit of wall,and the NPC will not consider it a home! Then they will move to the nearest available home.